# Воздействие на данные приложения через оперативную память

Tags: android, firebase, передача-данных

У меня есть небольшая игра, в которую играют игроки, я в ней реализовал  рейтинг по накопленным монетам, так получилось, что некоторые игроки, использовали ПО которое может воздействовать на мое приложение, (и не только) через оперативную память.

У меня нет сервера, я использую firebase для хранения данных, и я не могу очень часто сравнивать данные с базой данных, потому что, данные обновляются ежесекундно.

Я, реализовал у себя в приложении статическую базу данных, в которую поместил данные из firebase при входе в приложение, а когда пользователь покидает activity я обновляю данные.

Так вот этим некоторые игроки пользуются и изменяют данные через оперативную память, и у же потом эти данные сохраняются в облако.

Подскажите, как с этим бороться ?

Comment: а о каких данных речь?

Comment: Целочисленные и с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Так речь точно об __оперативной__ памяти а не о базе в ФС? Что у Вас есть "статическая база" - как Вы её создаёте? Если открывать базу без имени (если моя память не подводит)), то она создаётся в оперативке и улетучивается при закрытии. А если с именем - то полноценная с записью в файл - вот тут-то, имея рут, поправить её проще простого.

Comment: Stranger in the Q, да, это монеты и различные плюшки которые влияют на получение монет.

Comment: woesss,Под стическая, я имею ввиду класс со статическими полями в которых хранятся данные. Я не хочу создавать базу данных sql, так сложнее, а работать со статическими полями легче и доступны везде. У пользователей был рут.

Comment: woesss, может это не правильно, но у меня было мало времени на создание игры.

Comment: Если взлом примитивный: типа юзер смотрит сколько в игре денег, программа ищет это число в памяти и потом правит, то можно хранить его "неправильно" и эту неправильность учитывать при расчётах и выводе на экран. Если Вам известно как производится взлом - дополните вопрос чтобы можно было посоветовать что-то конкретное. Ещё можно хранить в нескольких местах и почаще делать внутренние проверки, раз делать онлайн сверки не хотите.

Comment: woesss, Да, это первый вариант, который вы описали с поиском конкретного числа. Я попробовал ваш вариант, но наверное я его уже испытывал. Дело в том, что, мне кажется, что математическое решение уже содержится в inputText `fun removeCoin(){
        StaticDataBase.Coin += StaticDataBase.speedCoin*2
        text.text = getFromDouble(StaticDataBase.Coin)
    }`

Comment: Наверное слишком простой вариант - юзеры реверснули Ваш код, подсмотрели как считается и подсчитали сами что искать, либо пересобрали/пропатчили игрушку. Нужно усложнить задачу, а против реверса лучше перенести хранение и расчёты очков, денег, ... и как можно больше кода в натив (нативный код декомпилировать гораздо сложнее). И там же делать проверку целостности кода, чтобы любой патчинг отваливался. В общем-то каждый разработчик должен придумать свою собственную защиту, потому как то что знают двое - уже не секрет;)

Comment: Мне рассказал как он это делает. Вы пользовались artMoney для взлома денег на пк? Есть подобная прога на андроид GameGuardian, только нужен рут. Вписываешь нужное значение в поиск, она находит и меняй значение как хочешь. С покупкой скилов я разобрался, там проверка непосредственно проходит через облако, а вот с накопление монет не могу так сделать, часто меняются данные. Я поступил таким образом, записываю игровой время, в onPause проверяю сколько игрок мог заработать монет за игровое время и сравниваю с суммой которая отображена на экране. Вроде работает, но могут быть ошибки.